Modbus tcp communication issues while using Twincat
I am using C# application to read and write data from a beckhoff ipc running twincat3. I am writing data to holding registers based on some events acyclically. Sometimes the data is write is not written to the beckhoff plc. I used wireshark to see if the C# application is sending a command to the server. i See that the command is executed but the data is not written to the plc. Also i see a lot of errors in the trace.
Like the image attached

Update : 16-12-2024
I used a 3rd party modbus tcp client  qModbusmaster to continuously read data and compared it with the wireshark packet of my application, from 1, I see that there is an ACK packet from client after every response, but whereas in the application code at some instances as highlighted the ACK is not received. Could this be a reason for the data/packet loss?

Below is the image taken when the registers are polled with qModmaster. There is no loss of packets


Show us the c# code?  From the trace it looks like you are trying to reuse the source port.  Which IP address is on the c# machine?

@RowanSmith The ip address of the pc running c# is 10.0.218.252, the beckhoff plc is 10.0.218.222.
But what i see in the trace is that the modbus tcp server sends a syn request

Those aren't actually errors - it's just the way that wireshark is highlighting them.  But your plc is continually trying to connect to the c# computer on port 502.  So why?  There are not any errrors in that trace the indicate a message wasn't sent to the PLC

@RowanSmith I am curious to know why would the plc (modbus tcp server) send a syn request to the c#(modbus tcp client). Usually the client initiates the connection request to the server by sending syn packet

It's not sending it to the c# client - it is trying to connect to the c# machine - so it is expecting the c# machine to be running a server that's listening on that port.  You will need to consult with your PLC documentation to find out why.  Maybe one of the commands you sent to the PLC told it to connect back to you??

In "my world", the PC / C# app is the (MODBUS) "master"; the plc or plc's, are the "slaves". The slaves have the "registers" etc; it's the master that issues the "write register" / "read register" commands. "Slaves" do not "speak" unless spoken to (via a master "broadcast" with a particular slave id.) I don't see how you can say a register wasn't written unless you parse the response from "read register".
